# Fade out table row not working for a model

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing a live search and I want those elements of a table which do not match the filter to fade out and those which match to show. However, this will not work:

Javascript:

```
    $("#filter").keyup(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'Search',
        success:
        function (result) {
            console.log(result.Books);
            var filter = $("#filter").val();
            console.log(filter);
            // Loop through each row of the table
            result.Books.forEach(
                (function (book, index) {
                    console.log(index);
                    var i = index;
                    var title = book.Title;
                    console.log(title);
                    if (title.search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                        $(table tr).fadeOut();

                        // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                    } else {
                        $(table tr).show();
                    }
                })
            )
        }

    });
});
```

My HTML:

```
    <table id="tableCurrentRented" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="webgrid-header">
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/AuthenticatedUser/SearchBooks?sort=Title&amp;sortdir=ASC">Title</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
<a href="/AuthenticatedUser/SearchBooks?sort=Author&amp;sortdir=ASC">Author</a>            </th>
            <th scope="col">
Available            </th>
            <th scope="col">
Rent            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td>A Christmas Carol</td>
            <td>Charles Dickens</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="10" data-title="A Christmas Carol">Yes</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td>aaa</td>
            <td>Aaa</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="11" data-title="aaa">Yes</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td>Charlotte Bronte</td>
            <td>Jane Eyre</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="7" data-title="Charlotte Bronte">Yes</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-alternating-row">
            <td>Emma</td>
            <td>Jane Austen</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="4" data-title="Emma">Yes</button></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="webgrid-row-style">
            <td>Far From The Madding Crowd</td>
            <td>Thomas Hardy</td>
            <td>Yes</td>
            <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" data-id="2" data-title="Far From The Madding Crowd">Yes</button></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

As you will notice, the function is comparing the title of the model with the filter.  If it matches, the row of that model should show. And if it does not match, it should fade out.  Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Try this: `$(table tr).find('td').fadeOut();`

Answer (score 0):

It should be like :

```
$("table tr").fadeOut();
```

and

```
$("table tr").show();
```

and not like `$(table tr).show();`. You missed double quotes to make it string.

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to filter the existing result I don't think you need a server side call. And you logic is not clear also. You tried a str.search , but if that result match then your code does not hold that particular tr.

You can try this code

```
            $(document).on('change', '#filter', function()){
                var filter_regex = new RegExp($( (this).val() + '').replace(/[.?*+^$[\]\\(){}|-]/g, "\\$&"), "i" );
                $('#tableCurrentRented tbody tr').each(function(){
                    var val = $(this)find('td:first').val();
                    if( ( val.search(filter_regex)) <0 ){
                        $(this).hide();
                    }else{
                        $(this).show();
                    }
                })
            }
```